# How do i add a new checkbox in message template

Tags: message-templates

I want to display a checkbox when the user clicks upload documents in message template. How should i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create an extension - see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/ to get started, and then you'll want to look at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/ to add the checkbox and then https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_postProcess/ to actually do something with it when the form is saved.

But also because the upload documents section is in a hidden section until you click the radio, if you want to add the checkbox in the same section you'll also need to look at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/region/#region-reference to put it in the right place, or maybe insert some javascript there that also hides/shows your checkbox when the radio is clicked.

Comment: Thank you very much @demerit. you answer is really helpful to me

Comment: my code is still not working. if i update my answer could you help me to resolve it?

Comment: If there's a specific problem then maybe, but usually back-and-forth detailed help works best if you go https://chat.civicrm.org and ask in the `dev` or `user-support` channel. Also stackexchange is terrible about update notifications.

Comment: ok thanks. i want to know can we call the civicrm_buildForm() function in different names on a same file ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - do you mean use one single buildForm() function to change two different pages in civi? You can use $formName to decide what to do inside the function. $formName will be different depending on what page you visit in civi.

Comment: no actually i asked to use two buildForm() in one file to change one page content in civi. mean i want to display two check boxes in the message template. so i'm trying the define the check box using two different buildForm functions in same php file. the first function is working but the second function is not.

Comment: Ok. You don't need a second buildForm(), you can just call `$form->add()` twice in the one buildForm() function.

Comment: thank you! you really helped me to understand the concept behind this. Thank you very much!